# Java swing, JLabel with html text not rendering properly on hovers

Tags: java, swing

I've come across this wierd interaction with my JLabel and html. If I use html in the string for the jlabel constructor and I hover over the JLabel it'll mess up my entire JPanel, putting everything up on one line and not respecting any bounds made to the components. But if I just use a simple string like "test", the hover effect works correctly.

The mouse enter and exit just brightens the color and puts it back again on exit.

```
text = "someString";
JPanel jp = new JPanel();

String str = "<html><div color='red'><u>"+text+"</u></div></html>";
JLabel jl = new JLabel(str);
jl.addMouseListener(this);
jp.add(jl);


@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    JLabel jl = (JLabel) e.getSource();
    currentJlColor = jl.getForeground();
    jl.setForeground(Color.decode("#c0c0c0"));
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    JLabel jl = (JLabel) e.getSource();
    jl.setForeground(currentJlColor);
}
```

Comment: Could you post the rest of your program as a [Runnable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as is, we don't know which layouts you're using or how

Comment: Your example doesn't change the layout for me. It also doesn't change any colors if they have been set. I think the html overrides the default color from the jlabel. Eg. http://pastie.org/10648145

Comment: The entire program consist of alot of code, and would just be confusing. I guess the answer I was looking for is below me. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are passing HTML formatted text you can not change the formatting of that text using the standard java library.

One possible work around would be to create strings with different formats as you need them and use the `SetText` method to change the `JLabel`

```
text = "someString";
JPanel jp = new JPanel();

String str1 = "<html><div color='red'><u>"+text+"</u></div></html>"; //color1
String str2 = "<html><div color='#c0c0c0'><u>"+text+"</u></div></html>"; //color2

JLabel jl = new JLabel(str1);
jl.addMouseListener(this);
jp.add(jl);


@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
  JLabel jl = (JLabel) e.getSource();
  currentString = jl.getText();
  jl.setText(str2); // this will change the text to color 2
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
  JLabel jl = (JLabel) e.getSource();
  jl.setText(str1); // Return to original color
}
```

Comment: Gonna use this method then. I'm guessing this was the problem then, since it worked if I didn't use html in my strings. Thanks for workaround!